# How can I concatenate the following python code as it done in Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, concatenation

I am trying to run this MATLAB code in Python:

```matlab
Y1=2;
YN=6
N=4;
n=(1:(N-1)).';
y=[(YN-Y1)/N.*n+Y1;YN];
y =

     3
     4
     5
     6
```

`y=3 4 5 6` is my answer in Matlab

The same code I am trying in Python which give me this results which is the same but I cannot concatenate `y2`.

```py
N,y1,y2=4,2,6
n=np.arange(1,N)
y =((y2-y1)/N*n+y1)
print(y)
answer--> array([3., 4., 5.])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, you have to use `np.append()`:

```
y = np.append(y,y2)
```

Answer (score 3):

In numpy, you want to use specific fucntions, it does not have an easy way like MATLAB's `[arr1, arr2]`. Note that this is just a shortcut of writing the `cat()` function in MATLAB.

Use one of the followings: [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) (for the general case, equivalent to `cat()`) or [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack) (`[arr1;arr2]`), [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack)(`[arr1,arr2]`), [`np.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy.dstack) (no MATLAB shortcut for this one) for specific dimensions.

Comment: Hey I dunno but this y = np.append(y,y2) works

Comment: @Mario yes, for your specific case yes, but its not a general solution for concatenation in numpy. `n=np.arange(1,N+1);y =((y2-y1)/N*n+y1);y[3]=y2` also works, but I'd not recommend it either.

Comment: Okay, Noted with thanks